# What would happen if the Grid computer was turned off? Would the programs and users die?

Tags: movie, tron

I'm wondering what would happen if Flynn's computer (or any computer running the Grid) was turned off?

Would the programs and users simply die?

Comment: I presume you haven't seen the end of Tron 2. Flynn's son turns off the Grid, but not before he's saved all the inhabitants and source files on a flash drive. Assuming he hadn't done so beforehand, the Grid and everybody in it would simply go "poof" into thin air.

Comment: Also this: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26927/what-happens-to-the-grid-if-the-system-is-shut-down

Comment: Oh ok, I have seen TRON legacy many times. But my question was what happens if there's a like a power failure, or the computer crashes, where does the grid go? I guess like what you said "poof" but is there not any more description visual information?