# What hardware was the new grid hosted on?

Tags: tron-legacy

After reading [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9041/whose-hardware-was-the-new-grid-hosted-on) question, I was wondering if anyone can identify the hardware that the grid was running on. It's obviously a Unix system, but beyond that, I'm not hip enough with late eighties hardware to know.

Is it an actual period machine, or is it just Hollywood prop magic?

Comment: Whatever it is, there's no record of it on [Starring the Computer](http://www.starringthecomputer.com/), a website devoted to computers in TV and movies.

Comment: @thedaian - there goes my productivity for the day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The screen details "SolarOS 4.0.1", "sun4m" and "i386" generated by the **uname -a** Unix command point to the computer being a [Sun 386i](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun386i), which is a workstation from the late 1980's.  As you can see from these [Google images](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&hl=en&source=hp&biw=1638&bih=1269&q=Sun386i&gbv=2&oq=Sun386i&aq=f&aqi=g-S1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=1030l1030l0l2077l1l1l0l0l0l0l197l197l0.1l1l0) the side cabinets in the movie are nothing like the real workstation, which in reality looked like any other beige mini-tower PC produced over the next decade.  As far as I know there weren't any tabletop touchscreen displays back then either, but Flynn was rich so he could have rolled his own.